# DAX Time Intelligence custom previous periods

Tags: ssas, powerpivot, powerbi, dax, tabular

My cube has a fact table with a "Sales" column.

There is a related Date Table "SalesDate" (properly marked as a Date Table)
I created a measure for "average sales" called [AvgSales]

There is also a measure for "past year average sales"

```
[AvgSales] := 
   AVERAGE([Sales])

[PY AvgSales] :=
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( 'SalesDate'[Date] ),
    CALCULATE (
        [AvgSales],
        DATEADD ( 'SalesDate'[Date], -1, YEAR )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

This works beautifully, and I can slice it in Excel like this: SalesDate[Year] on rows, SalesDate[Month] on columns.

The task at hand is to write a "past 5 year average sales" measure.

It is important that this measure will also work properly if you slice like described above (years on rows, months on columns)

I've spent a lot of time on http://www.daxpatterns.com/time-patterns/ but I'm really confused how to approach this properly.

Comment: Are you using a custom calendar? Otherwise, why not just use the built-in time intelligence functions?

Comment: I'm struggling to solve this with the built- in time intelligence functions. I can easily implement a comparison with any previous year.  

I'm struggling with comparing a single year with a 5-year period.  
What I want to do is compare the Average of e.g. 2016 with the ONE average over the 5-year period (2011, 2012, ... , 2016) - NOT the 5 single year averages.

Comment: Ah, I see. So for any given year-month (say, Jan 2016), it would look back over Jan 2011, Jan 2012, Jan 2013, Jan 2014, and Jan 2015 and compute the average sales for those year-months?

Comment: As long as your date table contains all the dates you want to filter your Sales table on, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796171/rolling-moving-average-by-month-over-years/31814665#31814665

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit simplistic but cant you just change the DATEADD function to -5 years?

[AvgSales] := 
   AVERAGE([Sales])

[PY AvgSales] :=
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( 'SalesDate'[Date] ),
    CALCULATE (
        [AvgSales],
        DATEADD ( 'SalesDate'[Date], -5, YEAR )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Your DAX formula lists the avarge of the year that is 5 years ago. What I am looking for are the past 5 years: The average over the 5 years { year-1, year-2, year-3, year-4, year-5 }